# How to extract second from date and time in python

Tags: python, datetime

By using:

```
import os,os.path,time,shutil,datetime

print time.ctime(os.path.getmtime("/home/sulata/Documents/source/"))

print time.ctime(os.path.getmtime("/home/sulata/Documents/destination/"))
```

I'm getting the outputs:

> Mon Apr  2 15:56:00 2018
>
> Mon Apr  2 15:56:03 2018

I want to get the time without seconds.

Comment: explain like giving input and expected output ?

Comment: Maybe you want time.strftime?

Comment: Would you rather have `Mon Apr 2 15:56 2018`, or `Mon Apr 02 13:27 2018`?

Comment: `datetime.date.today().strftime('%Y%m%d')`

Answer (score 2):

The general method is:

```
import time
time.strftime(format)
```

example:

```
>>>time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
20:08:40
```

In your case:

```
>>> time.strftime("%H:%M")
13:41

>>>time.strftime("%a %b %d %H:%M %Y")
'Mon Apr 02 13:27 2018'
```

if you want to remove the Zero, you could do something like this...

```
>>> time.strftime("%a %b "+str(int(time.strftime("%d"))) +" %H:%M %Y")
'Mon Apr 2 13:33 2018'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **datetime** to get the seconds.

**Ex:**

```
import os,os.path,time,shutil,datetime
print datetime.datetime.strptime(time.ctime(os.path.getmtime(r"/home/sulata/Documents/source/")), "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y").second
```

Answer (score 0):

JulioCamPlaz has already provided a decent enough solution, but if you want to maintain the date format, you can use regex for this:

```
import re

x = time.ctime(os.path.getmtime("/home/sulata/Documents/source/"))
print(re.sub(r':\d{1,2}\s', ' ', x))
```

What this does is that it removes the final two digits (seconds) of the time which are followed by a space, and replaces it with a space.

Although this may be an over-complicated method, it is short, and gives you the **exact** same date format without the seconds, and without altering it in any way.

Answer (score 0):

`getmtime` returns a timestamp, so you can format it using `strftime` to whatever format you need:

```
>>> import datetime as dt
>>> import os
>>> mTime = os.path.getmtime("/tmp/xauth-1000-_0")
>>> dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(mTime).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
'2018-04-01 22:07'
```

Format identifiers can be found in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this -

```
>>> import time, os
>>>
>>> x = time.gmtime(os.path.getmtime('/home/abhi/test.file'))
>>> 
>>> x
time.struct_time(tm_year=2018, tm_mon=4, tm_mday=2, tm_hour=11, tm_min=19, tm_sec=43, tm_wday=0, tm_yday=92, tm_isdst=0)
>>> x.tm_sec
43
>>> x.tm_hour
11
>>>
```